# Create .exe from .c and .s files gcc

Tags: gcc

I have a .c file programmed in C that calls a function that's programmed in Assembly at a .s file.

How can I create an executable file from these two?
I know that i have to use the flag -o, but for some reason it isn't working as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify all files on the command line. Gcc knows what to do with them by looking at the file extension.

```
gcc file1.c file2.s -o foo
```

should do the trick, unless you have forgotten to give us more info about which additional libraries to link with.

Comment: @JoãoSacramento Ok, the next thing then would be to *accept* this answer by clicking the green check mark to the left.